# ReactJs error: semicolon expected after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning how to use ReactJs and I am at the very beginning.

I have a HTML file which is simply this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="mainReact.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the file mainReact.js this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I get an error next to "render(){"
it says:

> Multiple markers at this line
> -primary expression expected
> -semicolon expected

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What are you compiling it with?..

Comment: That's the point: I don't understand what does it mean. I know I should use Babel for JSX but I don't know how to do it.
What I'm doing is litteraly writing those two files and opening index.html with my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) you have to use `React.createElement`.

If you check console it throws error `import outside of module`, you cannot use import because `js` files are not interpreted as ES modules, you must add in the nearest `package.json` that type has `module` value.

Check my update code below. Just change `mainReact.js`.

```
'use strict'
const e = React.createElement;

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return e('h1',null,'Hello World!');
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(e(Test), document.getElementById('content'));
```

A much easier solution is to run command `npx create-react-app my-app` read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Comment: @FabienneLablatte Did you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the line is JSX

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>;
```

JSX will not be compiled directly by browsers, so you can transpile the code like

```
ReactDOM.render(
React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello World!')
, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Notice `React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello World!')` is the alternative version of `<h1>Hello World!</h1>` which browser understands natively.

Thus you will need a transpiler to do that automatically, so use bable

if you want to jump directly onto React and don't want to scratch your head with bundler and transpilers then its better to use

**Create React App**
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 0):

You can  run npm init command to create a package.json file and then install Babel and webpack using npm. that should be able to do it. However that is a lot of work, I would suggest you to use create-react-app to create your project.